# SQL server level permissions

Tags: sql-server, security, permissions

I am aware of the Microsoft provided code to transfer logins between SQL servers, however this only does the account and the password.

What if that particular account has various roles and permissions assigned to it at a server level, is there an equivalent piece of code to script these permissions also?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found below script in my script repository that will help you. I have used it many times and its a life saver especially when you want to transfer database roles and object permissions from one server to another :

Credit goes to the original writer : Bradley Morris

```
--Script to Reverse Engineer SQL Server Object User Permissions

--Written By Bradley Morris
--In Query Analyzer be sure to go to
--Query -> Current Connection Options -> Advanced (Tab)
--and set Maximum characters per column
--to a high number, such as 10000, so
--that all the code will be displayed.



DECLARE @DatabaseUserName [sysname]
SET @DatabaseUserName = 'user_name_goes_here'

SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE
@errStatement [varchar](8000),
@msgStatement [varchar](8000),
@DatabaseUserID [smallint],
@ServerUserName [sysname],
@RoleName [varchar](8000),
@ObjectID [int],
@ObjectName [varchar](261)

SELECT
@DatabaseUserID = [sysusers].[uid],
@ServerUserName = [master].[dbo].[syslogins].[loginname]
FROM [dbo].[sysusers]
INNER JOIN [master].[dbo].[syslogins]
ON [sysusers].[sid] = [master].[dbo].[syslogins].[sid]
WHERE [sysusers].[name] = @DatabaseUserName
IF @DatabaseUserID IS NULL
BEGIN
SET @errStatement = 'User ' + @DatabaseUserName + ' does not exist in ' + DB_NAME() + CHAR(13) +
'Please provide the name of a current user in ' + DB_NAME() + ' you wish to script.'
RAISERROR(@errStatement, 16, 1)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SET @msgStatement = '--Security creation script for user ' + @ServerUserName + CHAR(13) +
'--Created At: ' + CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 112) + REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 108), ':', '') + CHAR(13) +
'--Created By: ' + SUSER_NAME() + CHAR(13) +
'--Add User To Database' + CHAR(13) +
'USE [' + DB_NAME() + ']' + CHAR(13) +
'EXEC [sp_grantdbaccess]' + CHAR(13) +
CHAR(9) + '@loginame = ''' + @ServerUserName + ''',' + CHAR(13) +
CHAR(9) + '@name_in_db = ''' + @DatabaseUserName + '''' + CHAR(13) +
'GO' + CHAR(13) +
'--Add User To Roles'
PRINT @msgStatement
DECLARE _sysusers
CURSOR
LOCAL
FORWARD_ONLY
READ_ONLY
FOR
SELECT
[name]
FROM [dbo].[sysusers]
WHERE
[uid] IN
(
SELECT
[groupuid]
FROM [dbo].[sysmembers]
WHERE [memberuid] = @DatabaseUserID
)
OPEN _sysusers
FETCH
NEXT
FROM _sysusers
INTO @RoleName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SET @msgStatement = 'EXEC [sp_addrolemember]' + CHAR(13) +
CHAR(9) + '@rolename = ''' + @RoleName + ''',' + CHAR(13) +
CHAR(9) + '@membername = ''' + @DatabaseUserName + ''''
PRINT @msgStatement
FETCH
NEXT
FROM _sysusers
INTO @RoleName
END
SET @msgStatement = 'GO' + CHAR(13) +
'--Set Object Specific Permissions'
PRINT @msgStatement
DECLARE _sysobjects
CURSOR
LOCAL
FORWARD_ONLY
READ_ONLY
FOR
SELECT
DISTINCT([sysobjects].[id]),
'[' + USER_NAME([sysobjects].[uid]) + '].[' + [sysobjects].[name] + ']'
FROM [dbo].[sysprotects]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[sysobjects]
ON [sysprotects].[id] = [sysobjects].[id]
WHERE [sysprotects].[uid] = @DatabaseUserID
OPEN _sysobjects
FETCH
NEXT
FROM _sysobjects
INTO
@ObjectID,
@ObjectName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SET @msgStatement = ''
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sysprotects] WHERE [id] = @ObjectID AND [uid] = @DatabaseUserID AND [action] = 193 AND [protecttype] = 205)
SET @msgStatement = @msgStatement + 'SELECT,'
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sysprotects] WHERE [id] = @ObjectID AND [uid] = @DatabaseUserID AND [action] = 195 AND [protecttype] = 205)
SET @msgStatement = @msgStatement + 'INSERT,'
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sysprotects] WHERE [id] = @ObjectID AND [uid] = @DatabaseUserID AND [action] = 197 AND [protecttype] = 205)
SET @msgStatement = @msgStatement + 'UPDATE,'
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sysprotects] WHERE [id] = @ObjectID AND [uid] = @DatabaseUserID AND [action] = 196 AND [protecttype] = 205)
SET @msgStatement = @msgStatement + 'DELETE,'
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sysprotects] WHERE [id] = @ObjectID AND [uid] = @DatabaseUserID AND [action] = 224 AND [protecttype] = 205)
SET @msgStatement = @msgStatement + 'EXECUTE,'
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sysprotects] WHERE [id] = @ObjectID AND [uid] = @DatabaseUserID AND [action] = 26 AND [protecttype] = 205)
SET @msgStatement = @msgStatement + 'REFERENCES,'
IF LEN(@msgStatement) > 0
BEGIN
IF RIGHT(@msgStatement, 1) = ','
SET @msgStatement = LEFT(@msgStatement, LEN(@msgStatement) - 1)
SET @msgStatement = 'GRANT' + CHAR(13) +
CHAR(9) + @msgStatement + CHAR(13) +
CHAR(9) + 'ON ' + @ObjectName + CHAR(13) +
CHAR(9) + 'TO ' + @DatabaseUserName
PRINT @msgStatement
END
SET @msgStatement = ''
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sysprotects] WHERE [id] = @ObjectID AND [uid] = @DatabaseUserID AND [action] = 193 AND [protecttype] = 206)
SET @msgStatement = @msgStatement + 'SELECT,'
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sysprotects] WHERE [id] = @ObjectID AND [uid] = @DatabaseUserID AND [action] = 195 AND [protecttype] = 206)
SET @msgStatement = @msgStatement + 'INSERT,'
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sysprotects] WHERE [id] = @ObjectID AND [uid] = @DatabaseUserID AND [action] = 197 AND [protecttype] = 206)
SET @msgStatement = @msgStatement + 'UPDATE,'
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sysprotects] WHERE [id] = @ObjectID AND [uid] = @DatabaseUserID AND [action] = 196 AND [protecttype] = 206)
SET @msgStatement = @msgStatement + 'DELETE,'
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sysprotects] WHERE [id] = @ObjectID AND [uid] = @DatabaseUserID AND [action] = 224 AND [protecttype] = 206)
SET @msgStatement = @msgStatement + 'EXECUTE,'
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sysprotects] WHERE [id] = @ObjectID AND [uid] = @DatabaseUserID AND [action] = 26 AND [protecttype] = 206)
SET @msgStatement = @msgStatement + 'REFERENCES,'
IF LEN(@msgStatement) > 0
BEGIN
IF RIGHT(@msgStatement, 1) = ','
SET @msgStatement = LEFT(@msgStatement, LEN(@msgStatement) - 1)
SET @msgStatement = 'DENY' + CHAR(13) +
CHAR(9) + @msgStatement + CHAR(13) +
CHAR(9) + 'ON ' + @ObjectName + CHAR(13) +
CHAR(9) + 'TO ' + @DatabaseUserName
PRINT @msgStatement
END
FETCH
NEXT
FROM _sysobjects
INTO
@ObjectID,
@ObjectName
END
CLOSE _sysobjects
DEALLOCATE _sysobjects
PRINT 'GO'
END
```

and

```
/*****************************************************************************************
*****************************************************************************************
*****************************************************************************************/

--Script to Reverse Engineer SQL Server Object Role Permissions

--Written By Bradley Morris
--In Query Analyzer be sure to go to
--Query -> Current Connection Options -> Advanced (Tab)
--and set Maximum characters per column
--to a high number, such as 10000, so
--that all the code will be displayed.



DECLARE @DatabaseRoleName [sysname]
--SET @DatabaseRoleName = '{Database Role Name}'
SET @DatabaseRoleName = 'role_name_goes_here'

SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE
@errStatement [varchar](8000),
@msgStatement [varchar](8000),
@DatabaseRoleID [smallint],
@IsApplicationRole [bit],
@ObjectID [int],
@ObjectName [sysname]

SELECT
@DatabaseRoleID = [uid],
@IsApplicationRole = CAST([isapprole] AS bit)
FROM [dbo].[sysusers]
WHERE
[name] = @DatabaseRoleName
AND
(
[issqlrole] = 1
OR [isapprole] = 1
)
AND [name] NOT IN
(
'public',
'INFORMATION_SCHEMA',
'db_owner',
'db_accessadmin',
'db_securityadmin',
'db_ddladmin',
'db_backupoperator',
'db_datareader',
'db_datawriter',
'db_denydatareader',
'db_denydatawriter'
)

IF @DatabaseRoleID IS NULL
BEGIN
IF @DatabaseRoleName IN 
(
'public',
'INFORMATION_SCHEMA',
'db_owner',
'db_accessadmin',
'db_securityadmin',
'db_ddladmin',
'db_backupoperator',
'db_datareader',
'db_datawriter',
'db_denydatareader',
'db_denydatawriter'
)
SET @errStatement = 'Role ' + @DatabaseRoleName + ' is a fixed database role and cannot be scripted.'
ELSE
SET @errStatement = 'Role ' + @DatabaseRoleName + ' does not exist in ' + DB_NAME() + '.' + CHAR(13) +
'Please provide the name of a current role in ' + DB_NAME() + ' you wish to script.'

RAISERROR(@errStatement, 16, 1)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SET @msgStatement = '--Security creation script for role ' + @DatabaseRoleName + CHAR(13) +
'--Created At: ' + CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 112) + REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 108), ':', '') + CHAR(13) +
'--Created By: ' + SUSER_NAME() + CHAR(13) +
'--Add Role To Database' + CHAR(13)
IF @IsApplicationRole = 1
SET @msgStatement = @msgStatement + 'EXEC sp_addapprole' + CHAR(13) +
CHAR(9) + '@rolename = ''' + @DatabaseRoleName + '''' + CHAR(13) +
CHAR(9) + '@password = ''{Please provide the password here}''' + CHAR(13)
ELSE
BEGIN
SET @msgStatement = @msgStatement + 'EXEC sp_addrole' + CHAR(13) +
CHAR(9) + '@rolename ''' + @DatabaseRoleName + '''' + CHAR(13)
PRINT 'GO'
END
SET @msgStatement = @msgStatement + '--Set Object Specific Permissions For Role'
PRINT @msgStatement
DECLARE _sysobjects
CURSOR
LOCAL
FORWARD_ONLY
READ_ONLY
FOR
SELECT
DISTINCT([sysobjects].[id]),
'[' + USER_NAME([sysobjects].[uid]) + '].[' + [sysobjects].[name] + ']'
FROM [dbo].[sysprotects]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[sysobjects]
ON [sysprotects].[id] = [sysobjects].[id]
WHERE [sysprotects].[uid] = @DatabaseRoleID
OPEN _sysobjects
FETCH
NEXT
FROM _sysobjects
INTO
@ObjectID,
@ObjectName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SET @msgStatement = ''
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sysprotects] WHERE [id] = @ObjectID AND [uid] = @DatabaseRoleID AND [action] = 193 AND [protecttype] = 205)
SET @msgStatement = @msgStatement + 'SELECT,'
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sysprotects] WHERE [id] = @ObjectID AND [uid] = @DatabaseRoleID AND [action] = 195 AND [protecttype] = 205)
SET @msgStatement = @msgStatement + 'INSERT,'
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sysprotects] WHERE [id] = @ObjectID AND [uid] = @DatabaseRoleID AND [action] = 197 AND [protecttype] = 205)
SET @msgStatement = @msgStatement + 'UPDATE,'
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sysprotects] WHERE [id] = @ObjectID AND [uid] = @DatabaseRoleID AND [action] = 196 AND [protecttype] = 205)
SET @msgStatement = @msgStatement + 'DELETE,'
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sysprotects] WHERE [id] = @ObjectID AND [uid] = @DatabaseRoleID AND [action] = 224 AND [protecttype] = 205)
SET @msgStatement = @msgStatement + 'EXECUTE,'
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sysprotects] WHERE [id] = @ObjectID AND [uid] = @DatabaseRoleID AND [action] = 26 AND [protecttype] = 205)
SET @msgStatement = @msgStatement + 'REFERENCES,'
IF LEN(@msgStatement) > 0
BEGIN
IF RIGHT(@msgStatement, 1) = ','
SET @msgStatement = LEFT(@msgStatement, LEN(@msgStatement) - 1)
SET @msgStatement = 'GRANT' + CHAR(13) +
CHAR(9) + @msgStatement + CHAR(13) +
CHAR(9) + 'ON ' + @ObjectName + CHAR(13) +
CHAR(9) + 'TO ' + @DatabaseRoleName
PRINT @msgStatement
END
SET @msgStatement = ''
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sysprotects] WHERE [id] = @ObjectID AND [uid] = @DatabaseRoleID AND [action] = 193 AND [protecttype] = 206)
SET @msgStatement = @msgStatement + 'SELECT,'
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sysprotects] WHERE [id] = @ObjectID AND [uid] = @DatabaseRoleID AND [action] = 195 AND [protecttype] = 206)
SET @msgStatement = @msgStatement + 'INSERT,'
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sysprotects] WHERE [id] = @ObjectID AND [uid] = @DatabaseRoleID AND [action] = 197 AND [protecttype] = 206)
SET @msgStatement = @msgStatement + 'UPDATE,'
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sysprotects] WHERE [id] = @ObjectID AND [uid] = @DatabaseRoleID AND [action] = 196 AND [protecttype] = 206)
SET @msgStatement = @msgStatement + 'DELETE,'
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sysprotects] WHERE [id] = @ObjectID AND [uid] = @DatabaseRoleID AND [action] = 224 AND [protecttype] = 206)
SET @msgStatement = @msgStatement + 'EXECUTE,'
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sysprotects] WHERE [id] = @ObjectID AND [uid] = @DatabaseRoleID AND [action] = 26 AND [protecttype] = 206)
SET @msgStatement = @msgStatement + 'REFERENCES,'
IF LEN(@msgStatement) > 0
BEGIN
IF RIGHT(@msgStatement, 1) = ','
SET @msgStatement = LEFT(@msgStatement, LEN(@msgStatement) - 1)
SET @msgStatement = 'DENY' + CHAR(13) +
CHAR(9) + @msgStatement + CHAR(13) +
CHAR(9) + 'ON ' + @ObjectName + CHAR(13) +
CHAR(9) + 'TO ' + @DatabaseRoleName
PRINT @msgStatement
END
FETCH
NEXT
FROM _sysobjects
INTO
@ObjectID,
@ObjectName
END
CLOSE _sysobjects
DEALLOCATE _sysobjects
PRINT 'GO'
END
```

Comment: If you feel that this answers your question, please upvote/mark answer !

Answer (score 5):

I have not personally tried this, but have a look the the Idera Permission Extractor:

**[Free Tool SQL Permissions Extractor](http://www.idera.com/productssolutions/freetools/sqlpermissionsextractor)**

If you need a sql solution, there is nothing built in. However, you can query the `sys.server_permissions` and `sys.database_permissions` tables. They contain the information needed to build the grant statements yourself. `sys.server_role_members` and `sys.database_role_members` contain the information needed to generate role membership scripts.

Comment: Hi thanks for this - I had come across that tool some time ago but it didn't support 64bit I will check it out to see if the new version does.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't mention what version of SQL so my answer is for SQL2008R2 in particular. Right click your DB in SSMS and select generate scripts then in the wizard that follows fill in as follows:

- Next
- Ensure "Script entire database and all database objects" is selected
- Tick users
- Next
- Click Advanced
- Find "Script Object-Level Permissions" and change to True
- Find "Script Logins" and change to True
- OK to leave Advanced
- (I would also select Save to new query-window)
- Next
- Next

I then dig through the resulting code and harvest out the code about the various securables (SPs usually) that I need by searching for the user name. Again, that is how **I** do it. There may be better but it has the benefit of not requiring external tools. Hope that is of some use.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some scripts I've been working on for something similar.  The queries themselves should be fine, the "scripting" parts are still a bit of a work in progress however.  @Paul's answer is probably your best bet though.

```
-- Server level roles
SELECT Logins.name AS UserName, Roles.name AS RoleName,
    'EXEC sp_dropsrvrolemember '+QUOTENAME(Roles.name,'''')+','+QUOTENAME(Logins.name,'''') + ';',
    'EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember '+QUOTENAME(Roles.name,'''')+','+QUOTENAME(Logins.name,'''') + ';'
FROM sys.server_role_members RoleMembers
JOIN sys.server_principals Logins
    ON RoleMembers.member_principal_id = Logins.principal_id
JOIN sys.server_principals Roles
    ON RoleMembers.role_principal_id = Roles.principal_id
--WHERE Logins.name LIKE '%MyLoginName%'



SELECT Grantee.name AS Grantee_Name, Grantor.name AS Grantor_Name,
    Permission.class_desc, Permission.permission_name,
    Permission.state_desc, 
    'REVOKE ' +
        CASE WHEN Permission.class_desc = 'ENDPOINT' THEN NULL
        WHEN Permission.[state]  = 'W' THEN 'GRANT OPTION FOR ' ELSE '' END +
        ' ' + Permission.permission_name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_CI_AS + 
        ' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(Grantee.name)  + '; ' AS Revoke_Statement,

    CASE WHEN Permission.class_desc = 'ENDPOINT' THEN NULL
        WHEN Permission.[state]  = 'W' THEN 'GRANT' ELSE Permission.state_desc COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_CI_AS  END +
        ' ' + Permission.permission_name  + 
        ' TO ' + QUOTENAME(Grantee.name)  + ' ' + 
        CASE WHEN Permission.[state]  = 'W' THEN ' WITH GRANT OPTION ' ELSE '' END + 
        ' AS '+ QUOTENAME(Grantor.name) + ';' AS Grant_Statement
FROM sys.server_permissions Permission
JOIN sys.server_principals Grantee
    ON Permission.grantee_principal_id = Grantee.principal_id
JOIN sys.server_principals Grantor
    ON Permission.grantor_principal_id = Grantor.principal_id
--WHERE Grantee.name LIKE '%MyLoginName%'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case if you want to move user databases from one server to another along with permissions. You can backed up the MSDB and Master Database and restore on the new instance along with user databases that take on all users, their permissions and other settings also.

Comment: Unfortunately at that point you lose any existing permissions, databases, jobs etc that were on your current server.  This works, but only if you are moving to a brand new server.